# How can I create three responsive divs using display: table and no JS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[image: Responsive design]

How can I create a responsive arrangement of three divs, such that:

1. when the viewport is narrow, the three divs appear one atop the other
2. when the viewport is average, the first div appears full width atop the other two, which are side-by-side *and have equal height*
3. when the viewport is wide, the three divs appear side-by-side with equal height

I would like the solution to be broadly supported by browsers.

I've tried a number of media query based strategies, as follows:

- To achieve #1, I style each div as `display:block`
- To achieve #2, I style the green and blue divs as `display:table-cell` and created a container div styled with `display:table`.

However, if I create another container div for all three elements and style it with `display:table`, neither of the following approaches work:

- Setting all divs to `display:table-cell` - because the red table cell and the other two are intervened by the smaller container div
- Setting the red div and the smaller container divs to `display:table-cell` - because the smaller container div still needs to be set to `display:table` for the sake of the green and blue divs inside it.

It's all a bit hard to explain, but I guess you have the idea. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit: I don't want to set the height of any div manually. It should be dictated by its content**

Comment: What do you mean by "narrow", "average", and "wide"? Please give us specific width criteria.

Comment: It doesn't matter at all. 100, 200 and 300px is fine, but it really makes no difference.

Comment: In the smallest view, do you want all three divs to be visible on the screen at once? We need to know what kind of content and how much will be in these divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is fairly difficult using `display: table` because of just the issue you ran into: containers are required and the configuration is not that flexible due to the way tables' strict requirements.

I suggest you use flexbox which has fairly good browser coverage now: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Here is a good example of how to get equal height rows using flexbox: http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback

Comment: You're probably right. I though about flexbox, but the IE support is weak. However, the JS fallback does make it more appealing. I'm going to tinker with it a bit. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I know @fauxserious already posted a very similar answer, but I'll post mine anyways because it's a bit different.

This doesn't use a table, nor the `::before` or `::after` CSS pseudo-elements.

```css
div#div1 {
    background-color: red;
}
div#div2 {
    background-color: green;
}
div#div3 {
    background-color: blue;
}
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    width: 31%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    div#div1 {
        width: 98%;
    }
    div#div2, div#div3 {
        width: 48%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    div {
        width: 98% !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

(It's best to see the above snippet if you open it in a new tab / window and resize it.)

See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/Lhfo6s75/1/) on JSFiddle.net.

**EDIT** See updated snippet. If you remove the `height` property of the `div`s (and replace it with `padding` so that you can see it even when it's empty), then the height will be determined by its content.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I should've been more clear, but I don't want to manually set the height of the divs. I want the content to determine the height.

Comment: The pseudo elements are used to preserve the height of the container.

Comment: @Mike and fauxserious: See updated snippet. All you have to do is take out the `height` and the height will be dictated by content. And to preserve a minimum height, I put in a `padding`. Simple as that!

Comment: This solution works remarkably well, albeit slightly hackier than kmiyashiro's flexbox proposal. Thanks everyone!

Comment: This doesn't ensure same height for the boxes in the same row.

Comment: I'm surprised this was selected at the right answer.  These aren't squares.

Comment: Oops, fauxserious is right. I tested the solution with terribly flawed methodology :| The boxes are not of equal height.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: sorry I missed the equal height part.

You are trying to make squares so let me code and then explain.  I'm going to make this a list to help identify things.  Assume the `ul` has been reset (no margin, padding or style-type).

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the CSS to make everything squares.

```
li{
   position:relative;
   width:33%;
   padding-top:33%;
}

li > div{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
}
```

You'll notice the padding to be equal to the width. Padding percentage no matter where it's used is based on the parent element's width (margin also works this way).  Even if you use it on the top or bottom.

Now with that we can get to positioning with CSS

```
ul:before, ul:after{
   content:"";
   display:table;
}

ul:after{
   clear:both;
}

li{
   position:relative;
   width:33%;
   padding-top:33%;
   float:left;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px){
   li{
      width:50%;
      padding-top:50%;
   }

   li:first-child{
      width:100%;
      padding-top:0; /* Not sure what height you'd want here*/
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width:400px){
   li{
      width:100%;
      padding-top:100%;
   }
}
```

Comment: Of course the `body` could just be the container for the `div`s.

Comment: I don't think this makes the divs equal height in the 2nd and 3rd scenarios.

Comment: Whoops, I missed the equal height part.  I'll reanswer.

Comment: Aww, I was just about to post the same answer. I'm too slow =) Media queries and RWD are the way to go!

Comment: It doesn't make them equal heights as previously commented. But thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Made some changes, this should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey fauxserious, first, they don't need to be squares. I can see the confusion based on my example illustration, but that's not a requirement. I just want any side-by-side divs to share the same height (which would be equal to the height of the div whose content is longest)

Comment: Oh, I would have used table cell then but ok.

Answer (score 0):

I was unsure of why you wanted to use **display: table;**, however I did something a little different but will look like the images you posted above.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box2"></div>
    <div class="box box3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
    width: 32.3333%; 
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    margin: .5%;
}

.box1 {
    background-color: #ff4034;
}

.box2 {
    background-color: #22ff62;
}

.box3 {
    background-color: #24a6ff;  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
    .box:first-child {
        width: 99%;
    }

    .box:nth-child(n + 2){
        width: 49%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 436px){
    .container .box {
        width: 99%;
        clear: both;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Result: Your images above

Answer (score 0):

How about using [flex](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/x64z3q7j/1/)?

```css
.parent {
    border: 1px solid #555;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.dual {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex: 2 2 550px;
}
.item {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    flex: 1 1 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="item" style="background-color: red">red</div>
    <div class="dual">
        <div class="item" style="background-color: green; flex: 1 1 100px">green</div>
        <div class="item" style="background-color: blue; flex: 1 1 100px">blue</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I had to tweak the sizes a little due to padding and margins, like ".dual" being 550px instead of 400px.  Also if the combined items are the same size they will show as two rows in the second column sometimes when shrinking so I made them smaller.  Make it full page when you run the snippet or check out the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/x64z3q7j/1/) which is easier to resize has some extra text showing the blue and green boxes keep the same height in layout 2.